# Can not get Eclipse work with Android ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

I have two machines with same problem. They are Linux Debian testing 64bits version.
I can't get Eclipse, run Androd ADT Plugin. I follow this instructions:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

<kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Install New Software</kbd> → <kbd>Available Software Sites</kbd>
ADT plugin is listed, and enabled:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Also enabled "Galileo Update Site"

I donwload **Android-sdk-linux_x86** (is there any 64 bits version????) and configure a Virual Device (2.3.3 version), I even run this virtual device (start) and works fine.

Eclipse version 3.5.2
Build id M20100211-1343

When I press <kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd>, there is not Android Section. When press <kbd>Window</kbd>, there is not any reference to ADT / AVD / Android.

Can someone help me!!

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install eclipse? I was having problems loading in some ADT's until I downloaded eclipse directly from their website and installed manually. The version available on the "linux market" is garbage IMO. This is shooting in the dark, but try downloading a tar from the website and loading it that way.

Comment: from debian packages sudo dpkg -l |grep eclipse
eclipse 3.5.2-11 // eclipse-cdt 6.0.2-1 // eclipse-jdt 3.5.2-11 // eclipse-pde 3.5.2-11 // eclipse-platform 3.5.2-11 // eclipse-platform-data 3.5.2-11 // eclipse-plugin-cvs 3.5.2-11 // eclipse-rcp 3.5.2-11

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have not pressed next after enabling the ADT plugin at the software installer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link and download the ADT plugin12 archive ---> http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-12.0.0.zip

GO to <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Install new Software</kbd> → <kbd>ADD</kbd>. Give any name to plugin and click on archive. Now browse your downloaded plugin file `ADT-12.0.0.zip` and click <kbd>Next</kbd>. Accept everything in the install procedure.